# PHP reference to string added in name

Tags: php, variables, reference

In a php file I want to create a variable which calls the string added to the php file name.
For example file named `index.php?=55`  (I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax)
...and inside the PHP set some variable which gets the string after `?=` to be used for later
`$id = self?=` something like that

Thanks.

Comment: It's `index.php?number=55` and you use `$_GET['number']` to fetch it.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php).

Comment: I would definitely checkout the manual, but a basic understanding of HTTP methods would help too. Basically there are some superglobals that PHP keeps around, and depending on what HTTP method you use is how those get populated. So, if you're using the GET method in your form, you'll use the $_GET super global to access the parameters sent in the URL :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to querystrings.

```
    index.php?id=2
```

In your php code you access the value of id via:

```
   $id = $_GET["id"];
```

The query strings come in name=value pairs so you can pass many like this:

```
   index.php?id=2&name=frank&boo=foo
```

And then you get each via:

```
    $_GET["name"]
```

etc. [This tutorial](http://www.ysquared.org/php/basics/use-the-query-string/) explains more.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

If the link is `?id=55`, `$id` will equal `55`